# Strange sreen at Impala installation in a docker container

Tags: docker, impala

To install impala in a Docker container (that use Ubuntu 16.04) I followed:

```
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IMPALA/Building+Impala
```

(Section: Building Impala (for developing Impala)). At some point of the installation I saw:

[image]

Does anyone knows what this message is about? I ended pressing my ESC key and :wq to allow the installation to continue but this left me intrigued.

Comment: Hi, it look like a simple database output from a select

Comment: Looks like it... but what could be its purpose?

Comment: well, the question is, does your installation work ? as for any outpout from ./configure or ./make can be tedious to debug anyhow.

Comment: It is working but I am still curious... this might have to be changed later. Thx